# Transform dataframe by grouping row

Tags: r, dataframe

`d1 <- data.frame(Gender=c('M', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F','F'), Age=c(15,38,17,35,26,24,20,26))`

And I'd like to transform it to look like this,if possible:

```
Gender Age
  M    15, 38, 17, 35
  F    26, 24, 20, 26
```

Comment: You should pause to reconsider this effort. Making dataframes "look like" a particular output display is likely to complicate things down the road. The first thing you should do is define why you want to display the data that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split by gender, then combine into your string, and finally combine:

```
spl = split(d1, d1$Gender)
spl = lapply(spl, function(x) data.frame(Gender=x$Gender[1],
                                         Age=paste(x$Age, collapse=", ")))
result = do.call(rbind, spl)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to display this, and I would advise not to "transform it",  you could do this:

```
 with(d1, aggregate(Age, list(Gender=Gender), list) )
  Gender              x
1      F 26, 24, 20, 26
2      M 15, 38, 17, 35
```

I noticed that @Henrik deleted his answer that used `aggregate.formula`, perhaps because of my answer which would be unfortunate because I was going to delete mine in favor of his. This is what he wrote and I think it's better than mine:

```
aggregate(Age ~ Gender, data = d1, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ", "))
```

But be on notice that both this and the earlier accepted answer both return those Age variables as factors.

Comment: That's true. I deleted my answer in favour of yours. I thought your `list` solution was a nice alternative - keeping the original age values and still get the formatting that was asked for. +1!

Comment: Oh, well. I guess I'll go search out a few of your answers to upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add the requisite `plyr` based solution:

```
library("plyr")
ddply(d1, .(Gender), summarize, Age = paste(Age, collapse = ", "))
##   Gender            Age
## 1      F 26, 24, 20, 26
## 2      M 15, 38, 17, 35
```